# URL structure and JSON on assemble.io with multiple index.html files?

Tags: assemble

I cant get Assemble to get correct index.json to correct index.hbs file. With this setup it takes only the last index.json file to populate both my index.hbs files.

Is this url structure possible with Grunt and Assemble?

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/src/pages/index.hbs
/src/pages/subfolder/index.hbs
```

and json data structure like

```
/src/data/index.json
/src/data/subfolder/index.json
```

and Gruntfile.js (assemble part) like this:

```
assemble: {
options: {
production: false,
        expand: true,
        site: '<%= pkg %>',
        assets: 'dist/assets',
        partials: ['src/includes/\*.hbs'],
        helpers: ['src/helpers/helper-\*.js'],
        layout: 'src/layouts/default.hbs',
        data: ['src/data/\*\*/\*.json']
    },
    pages: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'src/pages',
        src: ['\*\*/\*.hbs'],
        dest: 'dist/'
    }<br/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data in Assemble will merge together and be available at the top level.

Two options that I know of -

1. Rename the json files and call that within the index page you need.
2. Move each section into it's own assemble target and pass the data in that target's options object.

Let me know if that helps.